# 401 Not Authorized when using Twilio Enqueue verb with HTTP Basic Auth

Tags: twilio

When a user calls my number, Twilio makes a request of the format `https://username:password@www.myserver.com/my_secure_document` to my servers, which are protected by HTTP Basic Auth. This works great - Twilio logs in, sees an `Enqueue` verb, and remains logged in as it follows the `waitURL`.

However, after the user is dequeued by the other person hanging up (in this case, a Twilio Client), the Enqueue `action` URL is getting 401 Not Authorized responses.  Is this a bug in Twilio? The docs say that "Twilio will authenticate to your web server using the provided username and password and will remain logged in for the duration of the call". Shouldn't following the `action` of an Enqueue count as part of the call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, here's the workaround that worked for me: convert the `action` URL from a relative path to an absolute path, and provide the HTTP basic auth credentials again.